# Select2 not validating with jquery-validate plugin on Jquery 3.3.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-select2

I'm working on a project that requires me to use all the latest release of the jquery.

Issue is in my form i'm validating a select2 multiselect input and this validation is working on jquery 2.2.4. but somehow in jquery 3.3.1 thats not working. i'm using following code to ignore hidden inputs of select2 inputs and as i said its working on jquery 2.2.4

```js
$('.js-states').select2();

$.validator.setDefaults({
  ignore: ":hidden:not(.js-states)"
});

$("#this_form").validate({
  rules: {
    input_1: {
      require_from_group: [1, ".requered-group"]
    },
    input_2: {
      require_from_group: [1, ".requered-group"]
    },
    'input_3[]': {
      require_from_group: [1, ".requered-group"]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.0/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.0/dist/additional-methods.js"></script>

<form id='this_form'>
  <select class="js-states form-control requered-group" multiple="multiple" name="input_3[]" tabindex="-1" style="display: none; width: 100%;">
    <option value="all_services">ALL</option>
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
    <option value='3'>3</option>
  </select>
  <input type='text' name='input_1' class='requered-group'>
  <input type='text' name='input_2' class='requered-group'>
  <input type='submit' name='action' value='submit'>
</form>
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hhLahiru/d7hfa4nm/15/)

feel free to change jquery 3.3.1 to 2.2.4 and see how is working. thanks

Comment: Kindly include your code here instead of linking a JsFiddle

Comment: full code added.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery 3+ returns an empty array for select-multiple elements whereas before that it returned null. The validation plugin seems to treat this as a valid value.

From http://api.jquery.com/val/

> When the first element in the collection is a `select-multiple` (i.e., a
>   `select` element with the `multiple` attribute set), `.val()` returns an
>   array containing the value of each selected option. As of jQuery 3.0,
>   if no options are selected, it returns an empty array; prior to jQuery
>   3.0, it returns `null`.

You might have to write custom validations for this or request the issue to be fixed in the plugin itself.